# Code in commponent.ts file is not executed sequentially

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I have issue with below block of code.

```
  setCheckBoxValues(){
    this.selectedMaterials = []
    this.chooseAtleastOneError = true;//This Disables the button in my html page
    for (let key of Object.keys( this.formObj.materials )) {
      if(this.formObj.materials[key]){
        this.selectedMaterials.push(key);
        this.chooseAtleastOneError = false;//This Enables the button in my html page
      }
    }
  }
```

but the problem is as my code not executing sequentially. On click of checkbox for the second time Button in html page is enabled irrespective of whether checkbox is checked or unchecked.

#### HTML

```
<form (ngSubmit)="logForm()">

<ion-list>
  <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="formObj['unit_measure']" name="unit_measure">
    <ion-list-header>
        Unit
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-radio value="MPa" name="unit_measure" checked></ion-radio>
        <ion-label>SI(MPa)</ion-label>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-radio value="ksi" name="unit_measure"></ion-radio>
        <ion-label>ksi(English)</ion-label>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>
</ion-list>

<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<small *ngIf="chooseAtleastOneError">Choose atleast one material</small>
<ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of tempItems">
          <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col size=10>
                <ion-checkbox (click)="setCheckBoxValues()" class="float-left" [(ngModel)]="formObj.materials[item]" name="title"></ion-checkbox>
                <ion-label  class="float-left">{{item}}</ion-label>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col>
                <app-show-current-dataobj [material]="item"
                  (click)="dataService.setMaterialToModal(item)">
                </app-show-current-dataobj>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
        </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <app-add-custom-material></app-add-custom-material>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-button [(disabled)]="chooseAtleastOneError" type="submit" expand="full" [routerDirection]="'step100'" [routerLink]="['/step200']" navPop>Go</ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row> 
</ion-grid>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not a problem with the code. Its more to do with the checkbox not firing the event. You should be able to find related questions here.

Comment: can you please post your HTML here?

Comment: I found the answer. I changed click event to ionChang event it worked successfully. But still I am new to Angular world I am not sure of what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I changed click event to ionChang event in html it worked successfully. But still I am new to Angular world I am not sure of what I did.